# How do I know if I'm in a jail, container, snapshot, etc. environment?

Tags: ubuntu, users, jails

I received a machine (Ubuntu 12.04 server) from a coworker when he left the company. I created my own user as sudo/admin and used the machine for months via SSH. After rebooting for the first time since I was given the machine, I discovered that my user and everything I installed were missing. My user wasn't in the `/etc/passwd` file and the `/home/myuser` directory was missing. When I recreated the user and reinstalled everything, I didn't get any suspicious errors.

I suspect that I might have been in a snapshot/jail/container environment the whole time before rebooting, but how can I tell?

Comment: Part 2 of 3 - [How do I tell I'm running in a chroot?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/14346/37860)

Comment: See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/30851/22565 and http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/89714/22565 Try `imvirt`

Answer (score 0):

Part 3 of 3 (from [here](http://blog.scottlowe.org/2013/11/25/a-brief-introduction-to-linux-containers-with-lxc)):  `sudo lxc-list` to list the containers.  If there's one listed, you might start it and see if your user is there.

As for whether you were working in a snapshot, that would imply that some virtualization was operating.  Outside of looking for KVM: `sudo dpkg -l | grep -i kvm`, this is outside of the scope of the OS.